# How does the drools accumulate element work inside Optaplanner?

Tags: java, drools, optaplanner

I am wondering how the drools accumulate element work inside Optaplanner? It seems that the sum() function is not returning the value I expect. I have two simple POJOs `ProductionPackage` and `SKU`.

```
@PlanningEntity
public class ProductionPackage{ 
    // This is a custom date object containing information about a date. Constant Date initialized on start. 
    // Custom date object NOT util.Date or sql.Date
    private Date date;
    // The number of units in this package. Constant value initialized on program start.
    private int productionUnits;
    // The ID of the production package
    private int productionPackageId;

    // The SKU assigned to this production package
    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "skuRange")
    private SKU sku;
    
    // Getters, setters, constructors...
}

public class SKU {
    // Unique identifier for this product.
    private String sku;
    
    //Getters, setters, constructors...
}
```

The `PlanningSolution` looks as follows:

```
@PlanningSolution
public class ProductionPlan {

    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "skuRange")
    private List<SKU> skuList;

    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    private List<Date> dateList;

    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    List<ProductionPackage> ProductionPackageList;

    //Getters, setters, constructors...
}
```

Basically I have many `ProductionPackage`s and I am trying to assign one `SKU` to each production package. The `productionUnits` field of the 'ProductionPackage' specifies how much of the assigned `SKU` has to be produced. For simplicity, lets say that the `productionUnits` of all `productionPackage`s is `1`(could be any integer > 0).

One constraint of this problem is that there should be at least 10 units produced per `SKU` per `Date`. I am trying to implement this constraint using Drools as follows:

```
rule "At least 10 production units per SKU and per Day"
    enabled true
    when
        // Bind SKU to variable
        $sku : SKU()
        // Bind Date object to variable
        $date : Date()
        accumulate(
            ProductionPackage(sku == $sku,
            date == $date,
            $productionUnits : productionUnits);
            $productionUnitsTotal : sum($productionUnits);
            $productionUnitsTotal < 10
            )
    then
        // For debugging purposes
        System.out.println("SKU: " + $sku.toString());
        System.out.println("Date: " + $date.toString());
        System.out.println("ProductionUnits: " + $productionUnitsTotal);
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end
```

In the Drools documentation it is stated that the accumulate element iterates over all the elements of a collection. To me, this rule selects a combination of `SKU` and `Date`. It then iterates over the `ProductionPackageList` containing `ProductionPackage` objects. If the `Date` and `SKU` match with the previously selected `SKU` and `Date` objects it sums the `productionUnits`. I expect this to return the total units produced per `SKU` and per `Date` (and it looks like it does sometimes). However, I am noticing that the `System.out.println("ProductionUnits: " + $productionUnitsTotal);` statement is printing `0`. This is really odd to me since `productionUnits` is always an integer > 0. How can it print `0`? If both conditions match(`$date = date` and `$sku == sku`), an `SKU` should never have 0 production units because it is already assigned to a production package whose `productionUnits` > 0.

I think the error stems from the fact that I really don't understand what Optaplanner or Drools are doing. I have turned on DEBUG/TRACE mode however those haven't helped me much.

Comment: I think your problem is going to be the restriction you've applied: `$productionUnitsTotal < 10`. You can have all the positive productionUnits you want, but if they exceed the restriction, the total is going to remain 0. Try removing that restriction from the accumulate and see what happens.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas If I remove the restriction the println statement prints numbers >0 but the vast majority of them print 0.

Comment: Then it's likely that the vast majority of your inputs actually have values of 0. The ones that do print numbers > 0 are the ones that have legit value but which were being blocked by the restriction. I would suggest checking your inputs (that Date condition is somewhat suspicious .... could you have a rounding problem?)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I have checked that and I am actually initializing my objects with really high values using a test database.  Sometimes the productionUnits is greater than 1500 and I get the same results. I am using ints everywhere so I don't think it is rounding. It seems that when drools doesn't find a match it is returning a default value of 0.

Comment: If most of your values are very high than a `< 10` restriction really is the most likely culprit here...